# Javascript group objects by property

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, underscore.js

I'm trying to group objects in an array by date:

```
var list = [
     {
         date: "2017-01-01",
         type: "type1",
         amount: 100
     },
     {
         date: "2017-01-01",
         type: "type2",
         amount: 150
     },
     {
         date: "2017-01-02",
         type: "type1",
         amount: 200
     }
]
```

And I'm trying to get something like:

```
var dateArr = [
   {
      date: "2017-01-01",
      activities: [
        {
           type: "type1",
           amount: 100
        },
        {
           type: "type2",
           amount: 150
        }]
   }
]
```

I have tried a few things...like this using underscore (from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15888912/4989305):

```
var dateArr = _
.chain(list)
.groupBy('date')
.map(function(value, key) {
    return {
        date: key,
        activities: [{
            type: _.pluck(value, 'type'),
            amount: _.pluck(value, 'amount')
        }]
    }
})
.value();
```

I've also tried this (from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31373860/4989305)

```
var dateArr = {};
list.forEach(function(item){
    dateArr[item.date] = dateArr[item.date]||[];
    dateArr[item.date].push(item);
});
```

But, for some reason both return empty.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `list.forEach(` one works just fine. `dateArr` just isn't an array, but an object. Try `console.log(dateArr)` after your last snippet.

Comment: Your first attempt returns exactly the output you described. And as Cerbrus points out, the second one works too. It seems you have a problem with how you are observing the result.

Comment: mmm...curious to say the least...will have another look.
console.log gives me empty arrays though. I'll have to go through it bit by bit again to see. Thanks for help though - at least I know now it should work in principal.

Comment: Ah - figured it out. It was a IndexedDB transaction that was not completing in time. Dexie's `then()` function fixed it.

Answer (score 24):

A few lines of modern JavaScript will get you the result you want:

```
var dateArr = Object.values(list.reduce((result, {
    date,
    type,
    amount
}) => {
    // Create new group
    if (!result[date]) result[date] = {
        date,
        activities: []
    };
    // Append to group
    result[date].activities.push({
        type,
        amount
    });
    return result;
}, {}));
```

Explaination:

1. Use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to consolidate the list into a set of results, a plain object, grouped by date.
2. The consolidate function [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) the item into three parameters.
3. It then creates a new group if necessary.
4. Current item's type and amount is then pushed to the group as part of an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015).
5. The same set is returned to the `reduce`, so that the next item will consolidate into the same set.
6. Use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to extract the values from the set. (Drop the keys)

Answer (score 6):

You could use a hash table for groupiung by date and assign the single group to the result array.

```js
var list = [{ date: "2017-01-01", type: "type1", amount: 100 }, { date: "2017-01-01", type: "type2", amount: 150 }, { date: "2017-01-02", type: "type1", amount: 200 }],
    result = [];

list.forEach(function (hash) {
    return function (a) {
        if (!hash[a.date]) {
            hash[a.date] = { date: a.date, activities: []};
            result.push(hash[a.date]);
        }
        hash[a.date].activities.push({ type: a.type, amount: a.amount });
    };
}(Object.create(null)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 4):

I hope this is what you exactly need.

```js
var list = [
     {
         date: "2017-01-01",
         type: "type1",
         amount: 100
     },
     {
         date: "2017-01-01",
         type: "type2",
         amount: 150
     },
     {
         date: "2017-01-02",
         type: "type1",
         amount: 200
     }
]
var dateArrKeyHolder = [];
var dateArr = [];
list.forEach(function(item){
    dateArrKeyHolder[item.date] = dateArrKeyHolder[item.date]||{};
    var obj = dateArrKeyHolder[item.date];
    if(Object.keys(obj).length == 0)
    dateArr.push(obj);
    
    obj.date = item.date;
    obj.activities  = obj.activities || [];
    
    obj.activities.push({type:item.type, amount: item.amount });
});


console.log(JSON.stringify(dateArr));
```

Comment: @Funktion so after a year has passed, what are your compare/test results? :P

Comment: @Pascal I unfortunately don't have access to that project at the moment, but as I recall I used the last solution by chindirala - only because I tried it and it worked straight out of the box. Might need this again for a current project actually, so will see how it goes.