# GroupBy array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have this array of objects

```
[
  {
    "countryCode": "US",
    "countryName": "United States",
    "stateId": "1",
    "stateName": "Alabama",
    "cityId": "1",
    "cityName": "Montgomery"
  },
  {
    "countryCode": "US",
    "countryName": "United States",
    "stateId": "2",
    "stateName": "Alabama",
    "cityId": "2",
    "cityName": "Birmingham"
  },
  {
    "countryCode": "US",
    "countryName": "United States",
    "stateId": "2",
    "stateName": "Alaska",
    "cityId": "1",
    "cityName": "Anchorage"
  }
]
```

that I would like to convert to an object like the following

```
{
  "countryCode": "US",
  "countryName": "United States",
  "states": [
    {
      "stateId": 1,
      "stateName": "Alabama",
      "cities": [
        {
          "cityId": 1,
          "cityName": "Montgomery"
        },
        {
          "cityId": 2,
          "cityName": "Birmingham"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "stateId": 2,
      "stateName": "Alaska",
      "cities": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Anchorage"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried lodash's `groupBy` as `var grouped = _.groupBy(data, 'countryCode')` but what I got is

```
{
  HN: [
    {
      countryCode: 'US',
      countryName: 'United States',
      stateId: '1',
      stateName: 'Alabama',
      cityId: '1',
      cityName: 'Montgomery'
    },
    {
      countryCode: 'US',
      countryName: 'United States',
      stateId: '1',
      stateName: 'Alabama',
      cityId: '2',
      cityName: 'Birmingham'
    },
    {
      countryCode: 'US',
      countryName: 'United States',
      stateId: '2',
      stateName: 'Alaska',
      cityId: '1',
      cityName: 'Anchorage'
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't want the value of the property's name in which the data will be grouped by to be the key, I want the property's name being grouped by to be set as key and then create a custom property as an array to list all of the cities of a state, is there anyway to achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: I’d recommend to use operators such as reduce rather than trying to get groupBy or similar to somehow work. You’ll spend more time getting lo dash shorthand to work rather than using reduce.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderStaroselsky, I'll have that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. This is also *almost* a duplicate of [Javascript group objects by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42480663/javascript-group-objects-by-property/42484070)

```js
x = [{
        "countryCode": "US",
        "countryName": "United States",
        "stateId": "1",
        "stateName": "Alabama",
        "cityId": "1",
        "cityName": "Montgomery"
    },
    {
        "countryCode": "US",
        "countryName": "United States",
        "stateId": "1",
        "stateName": "Alabama",
        "cityId": "2",
        "cityName": "Birmingham"
    },
    {
        "countryCode": "US",
        "countryName": "United States",
        "stateId": "2",
        "stateName": "Alaska",
        "cityId": "1",
        "cityName": "Anchorage"
    }
];

var stateArray = Object.values(x.reduce((result, {
    countryCode,
    countryName,
    stateId,
    stateName,
    cityId,
    cityName
}) => {
    // Create new group
    if (!result[0]) result[0] = {
        countryCode,
        countryName,
        states: []
    };
    // Append to group
    let state = -1;
    for (let i = 0; i < result[0].states.length; i++) {
        if (result[0].states[i].stateId == stateId)
            state = i;
    }
    if (state == -1) {
        result[0].states.push({
            stateId,
            stateName,
            cities: [{
                cityId,
                cityName
            }]
        });
    } else {
        result[0].states[state].cities.push({
            cityId,
            cityName
        });
    }
    return result;
}, {}));

console.log(stateArray)
```

Comment: Yeah just what I was looking for, thank you! Didn't find that question when looking for a similar solution though, should've looked up a bit more, anyway thanks!