# Manipulate Object with JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this object:

```
const data = {
    Jan: [{product: 'Shirt', num: '13'}, {product: 'Shoes', num: '15'}],
    Feb: [{product: 'Shirt', num: '22'}, {product: 'Shoes', num: '1'}],
    Mar: [{product: 'Shirt', num: '15'}, {product: 'Shoes', num: '25'}]
}
```

I need to create another object that looks like this:

```
const data = {
    labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'],
    datasets: [
    {
        label: 'Shirt',
        data: [13, 22, 15]
    },
    {
        label: 'Shoes',
        data: [15, 1, 25]
    }
    ]
  }
```

The object above is for a chartJs. The data array in the datasets array, correspont to each value for the product per month.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Where do the colours come from? Where's your effort so far?

Comment: The colors are irrelevant. I will delete them

Comment: The `labels` are `Object.keys(data)`. The datasets are grouped. You can find dozens of duplicates.

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?  I imagine you could get your `labels` from the keys in the object you have.  And you could loop over the data you have (maybe more than once) to build your `datasets` and the `data` within them.

Comment: Yes, the labels are fine with Object.keys(). I have tried looping with a for in, but I am failing to see how to build up the datasets

Comment: For the datasets you can use [Javascript group objects by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42480663/javascript-group-objects-by-property) with `Object.values(data).flat()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the dataset using `Array.prototype.reduce` and create the new data array.

Note that you have to flatten the array as the `Object.values(data)` gives you an array of array.

```js
const data = {
    Jan: [{product: 'Shirt', num: '13'}, {product: 'Shoes', num: '15'}],
    Feb: [{product: 'Shirt', num: '22'}, {product: 'Shoes', num: '1'}],
    Mar: [{product: 'Shirt', num: '15'}, {product: 'Shoes', num: '25'}]
};

// Iterate through the data object's value and flatten this
// For example the Object.values(data) will provide you-
// [[{product: 'shirt', num: '13'}, {product: 'Shoes', num: '15'}], [{product: 'Shirt', num: '22'}, {product: 'Shoes', num: '1'}]] so on and so forth
// Need to make this a linear array using flat(1)

const dataset = Object.values(data).flat(1).reduce((acc, curr) => {

  // Check if the product exists on the accumulator or not. If not then create a new
  // object for the product.
  // For example, this will create - {'Shirt': {label: 'Shirt', data: [13]}}
  if (acc[curr.product] === undefined) {
    acc[curr.product]  = {
      label: curr.product,
      data: [Number(curr.num)]
    }
  } else {
    // If the product already exists then push the num to the data array
    acc[curr.product].data.push(Number(curr.num))
  }
  
  return acc;
}, {});



const newData = {
  labels: Object.keys(data), // Set the keys as the labels
  dataset: Object.values(dataset) // dataset is an object, just extract the values as an array
}

console.log(newData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{ min-height: 100vh!important; top: 0;}
```

Comment: Thank you @Sajeeb. I will spent all the time I need to understand this, and learnt from it.

Comment: I've just write some comments so that you could understand easily.